# Merge two associative arrays without reindexing - PHP

Tags: php, indexing, merge, associative-array, array-merge

Without re-indexing how can I merge 2 associative arrays? I prefer not to use foreach or for loop, any better idea?

```
$a1=array(555=>array('name'=>'First Name','surname'=>'Second Name'), 888=>array('name'=>'New First Name','surname'=>'New Second Name'));
$a2=array(888=>array('invite'=>false), 555=>array('invite'=>true)); 
$result=array(555=>array('name'=>'First Name','surname'=>'Second Name', 'invite'=>true), 888=>array('name'=>'New First Name','surname'=>'New Second Name', 'invite'=>false));
```

Comment: where is element `888` in the result array? is this a typo?

Comment: @Anant I have edited the index in my question.. I want to merge these 2 arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `array_replace_recursive` to add invite items to corresponding  source array elements

```
array_replace_recursive($a1, $a2);
```

[demo](https://eval.in/593340)

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge` function or `$a1 + $a2`.

Comment: Difference is in duplicate keys: use first or replace to last same key.

Comment: And add ksort(&$arr) to result array if you wish to sort by keys.

Comment: **array_merge returns** 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => First Name [surname] => Second Name ) [1] => Array ( [name] => New First Name [surname] => New Second Name ) [2] => Array ( [invite] => ) [3] => Array ( [invite] => 1 ) )'   and **$a1 + $a2** Array ( [555] => Array ( [name] => First Name [surname] => Second Name ) [888] => Array ( [name] => New First Name [surname] => New Second Name ) )

Comment: @Steffi sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) function

```
$a1=array(555=>array('name'=>'First Name','surname'=>'Second Name'), 888=>array('name'=>'New First Name','surname'=>'New Second Name'));
$a2=array(888=>array('invite'=>false), 555=>array('invite'=>true));
print_r(array_replace_recursive($a1, $a2));
```

This would print:

```
Array ( [555] => Array ( [name] => First Name [surname] => Second Name [invite] => 1 ) [888] => Array ( [name] => New First Name [surname] => New Second Name [invite] => ) )
```